# What is meant by lightweight server in python django

Tags: django

I was reading django basics document from [tutorials point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/django/django_basics.htm) , i came across term " lightweight server ". What does lightweight mean?

Answer (score 1):

the django dev server is single-threaded, no security concerns and watches the project files to enable auto-reloading.  Its good for a development environment, but should never be put into production.

`lightweight` here means its pretty minimal and stripped down to meet a single use case.

Comment: The contrast to `light weight` would be `Apache` or `Nginx` that would be used in production but are more work to configure.

Comment: Ok i got it..thnx